# Overlay callout to empty space on map

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap, layers, overlay, callout

Is it possible to make a callout on the Overlay / box to place on map it outside the coordinates, so that we use an empty space to place the overlay. This is because if we have several overlay elements that are close to each other and something overlaps, we can split them out.

Exs:

[image]

Comment: It is possible, but it would require some coding.

Comment: @TomazicM How is it possible when everything that is presented in a map needs a coordinate? Do you have any examples I can look at?

Comment: Sorry, no examples.